# How to make others access my computer via Internet?

Tags: apache2

I am running Ubuntu, and have installed Apache. When I input my IP address on a web browser, I see the following message:

```
File browser: main.sh
```

`main.exe` is a file which exists in `/var/www/` in my computer, and also, the html `index.html` also exists in the folder:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
File Browser
</head>
<body>
<a href = "/main.py">main.sh</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to let others download my file in `/home/user/anotherfile.sh`, except moving `anotherfile.sh` to `/var/www`, how can I let others access that file?

If using Apache is inconvenient, any other ideas that implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a symlink (short for symbolic link) in the /var/www/ to point to the file in /home/user/anotherfile.sh. The command would be:

```
cd /var/www/
sudo ln -s /home/user/anotherfile.sh anotherfile.sh
```

The format of the comand is

```
ln -s $TARGET $LINK_NAME
```

The -s option is required to create a symbolic link.

It will create the symlink /var/www/anotherfile.sh that will point to /home/user/anotherfile.sh

You could do that to folders too. That's what I do when I need to share a file.

Comment: thx, its a good idea